# Angular HTTP Basic Auth logout header change ignored

Tags: angularjs, http-headers

I'm using basic HTTP auth (without SSL for testing).

The login works fine, we send an `$http` request with the authorization header and if the login is correct, it works.

For logout, I'm setting the Authorization header to a bad value and sending an `$http` request to "trick" the server.  The server seems to ignore the new changed auth header.  I verified with developer tools in FF that the header value is all ones, but the request is still successful.

How do I "logout"?  The logout function sends a bad Authorization header, and the browser sends it according to firebug.  What's going on?  This is a Java EE 7 app with Wildfly 9 and Shiro, if that makes a difference.

Here is the code:

```
var DataFactory = function($http, $rootScope, $base64, $cookieStore) {

    var _debug = false;
    function _d(message) {
        if (!_debug) {
            return;
        }
        console.log(message);
    }

    function setDebug(flag) {
        _debug = flag;
    }

    function doLogout() {
        _d("Logging out");
        $rootScope.globals = {};
        $cookieStore.remove('globals');
        $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic 111111111111111111';
        $http.get(
                'http://localhost:8080/myapp/rest/v1/svc')
                .then(function(data) {
                    alert("Logout: " + JSON.stringify(data.data));
                }, function(data) {
                    alert("Logout Error: " + JSON.stringify(data))
                });
    }

    function doLogin(username, password) {
        var token = $base64.encode(username + ":" + password);
        _d("Logging " + username + " in with token " + token);

        $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + token; // jshint
        // ignore:line
        $rootScope.globals = {
            token : token,
            username : username
        };
        $cookieStore.put("globals", $rootScope.globals);
        _d("Login finished, globals are: " + JSON.stringify($rootScope.globals));
        $http.get(
                'http://localhost:8080/myapp/rest/v1/svc')
                .then(function(data) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data.data));
                }, function(data) {
                    alert("Error: " + JSON.stringify(data))
                });
    }
    ;

    return {
        setDebug : setDebug,
        doLogin : doLogin,
        doLogout : doLogout
    };
}
```

Comment: Basic auth is sending user & password with each request. What is logout?

Comment: I want the browser to forget the username and password, or use an invalid one (thus the code: `$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic 111111111111111111';` to set a "bad" authentication string...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sending your own authorization string within a XHR request will not magically delete the information cached in the browser. Basic authentication has no concept of logging out. The only way to "logout" with basic authentication is to make the credentials invalid at the server, i.e. change username and/or password so that the stored credentials do not work any longer.

Comment: Right, and by modifying the header and sending the request that should do it, right?  It's in the code I posted.

Comment: @mikeb: You are doing a request with a manual auth response on the client side. This will not change the credentials the server expect and it will also not change the credentials  cached at the client. Again: there is no logout for basic auth and the only way is to "...change username and/or password so that the stored credentials do not work any longer.". "Change" in this case is a really change at the server and not simply using different credentials for a single request by the client.

Comment: OK, so you mean change the password that the server is expecting?  So if my valid login is test/test, I would actually have to change the server-side permissions as there is no way to tell the client to release the credentials?

Comment: @mikeb: yes. There is not way to clear the stored credentials in the client apart from that they don't work any longer. Basic auth has a concept of an authorized user but not a concept of logging in or logging out.

Comment: Also as soon as you close your client that is browser in this case the authorization will be removed and you need to authorize again. So till client is alive it remains authenticated.